# Verifying the Python package compatibility of PIP

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, pypi

Previously, I installed a specific Python package.

My Python environment was version 3.5.9, and the package I was going to install was as follows.

I have a NEXUS Repository
I upload and use python packages that I like to use in the repository.
I used it normally and uploaded additional latest versions of some packages.

After that, there was a Python package installation error.

↓ The following is the installation log of llvmlite

```
Collecting llvmlite>=0.28.0dev0 (from numba==0.43.1->-r /tmp/requirements.txt (line 6))
  1 location(s) to search for versions of llvmlite:
  * http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/
  Getting page http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/
  http://10.253.225.6:8081 "GET /repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2914
  Analyzing links from page http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/
    Found link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.36.0/llvmlite-0.36.0.tar.gz#md5=0af63891993526bee21eaa408ce56cfe (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/), version: 0.36.0
    Found link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0.tar.gz#md5=2e0b4586a8c8c1981ce49e837bf70781 (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/), version: 0.28.0
    Skipping link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=6588594ad55a67f248d31712a716654d (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_i686.whl#md5=746127c2493947a8437bfe0c324ebc72 (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=10191b37db21e01beb0ee5895f12f85f (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_i686.whl#md5=90ed888ae45fd95306646dcbb22d0a8f (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Found link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=7cef11f191acb58c5149bfad3ee9fd01 (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/), version: 0.28.0
    Skipping link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_i686.whl#md5=108739fdcde2547d10d120ba405171c9 (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=4ad41048e28167b63486edb1f0f40d56 (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_i686.whl#md5=f1c00bc8a7914303654a333f8f7f4508 (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=f1799c47f721b0655a8f5d42fdbcad6d (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Skipping link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=145fbb53ebc081144a3d775f0908f5a4 (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/); it is not compatible with this Python
    Found link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-1-cp35-cp35m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=41a71b4f6c607c1f00a89fa61e81e13f (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/), version: 0.28.0
    Skipping link http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/packages/llvmlite/0.28.0/llvmlite-0.28.0-1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=5ecda86d4835aae6f6d326c88d938e17 (from http://10.253.225.6:8081/repository/pypi-repo/simple/llvmlite/); it is not compatible with this Python
  Using version 0.36.0 (newest of versions: 0.28.0, 0.36.0)
```

pip found that there were two versions of the installable package. (0.28.0, 0.36.0)

However, since 0.36.0 is a newer version, a message popped up saying that 0.36.0 will be
installed, and I installed 0.36.0 version.

```
 Using version 0.36.0 (newest of versions: 0.28.0, 0.36.0)
```

As shown in the log above, llvmlit/0.36.0 of the first "Found link" should not be adopted.
The reason is that 0.36.0 can only be installed in Python 3.6.x versions or higher.

I wonder why pip recognized version 0.36.0 as an installable package.

That's why I tried to investigate pip's official github source code,
but I can't find which source code is the file that checks python package compatibility.

I want to see the source code verifying the Python package compatibility of PIP

Where and how can I find the source code where the pip checks the compatibility of the Python package?

(I want to analyze the source code accurately and know exactly why that package was adopted as an installable package.)

thank you